# How do I stop my loop from iterating the last value twice?

Tags: excel, vba

When running the loop, the last value is always transferred twice no matter how many rows there are.

I have tried `.offset` and +/- to lastrow.

```
Public MySession As Reflection.Session
Option Explicit

Sub getData()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim question As String
Dim answer As String

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set MySession = New Reflection.Session

With ws
    lastrow = getlastrow
    With MySession

        On Error GoTo qHandle
        For i = 2 To lastrow
            question = ws.Cells(i, 1).Value

            On Error GoTo aHandle
            If question = "" Then
                'do nothing
            Else
                .TransmitANSI question
                .TransmitTerminalKey rcIBMEnterKey
                ws.Cells(i, 2).Value = MySession.GetDisplayText(1, 2, 3)
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

        Next i
        On Error GoTo 0

    End With
End With

Exit Sub

qHandle:
    MsgBox "There was a problem with the question, " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub

aHandle:
    MsgBox "There was a problem with the answer, " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```

End result should be printing of values to sheet corresponding to the input row. Everything works fine with no errors, but the last value is iterated twice, causing an extra row in column 2 but not column 1.

This is my function to get lastrow.

```
'Return Value of Last Row
Public Function get_LastRow() As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
With ActiveSheet
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                      After:=.Range("A1"), _
                      Lookat:=xlPart, _
                      LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                      SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                      SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                      MatchCase:=False).row
    Else
        LastRow = 1
    End If
    get_LastRow = LastRow
End With
End Function
```

Comment: I think it would be more beneficial to see the function of `getlastrow`.

Comment: Your description sounds like a too fast shortcut. You are stating that the "last value is iterated twice", which might be not true. Maybe there is an error in evaluating which row is the last row, and then it might be that the first column is NOT empty (maybe containing `" "`?) and then the loop behaves normally. I do  not understand the statement "last value is iterated twice" in this context.

Comment: If you replace `lastrow = getlastrow` with `lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).row`, the problem persists?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs I updated my post with my `getlastrow` function. At the beginning the sheet is blank except column A.

Comment: @HonzaZidek In my column A is a list of values that varies in length. I determine the last row then start from row 2 (row 1 is headers) and input until last value. In column B, say column A has 10 values, then at the end B has 11. The 11th being value 10 repeated. Meaning row 11 col A is empty and col B has a row 10 col B value.

Comment: If `lastrow` is really (eg) 10 I don't see anything in your code which could explain how a value gets populated to row 11.  Have you tried debugging/stepping through your code as it runs?

Comment: @TimWilliams Yes, and I'm thinking you are wondering if I paid close attention to the value of last row throughout? I remember it stepping through fine, i was paying more attention to the end result on the sheet though, so possibly it increased last row somehow? But this method works on other things I use it for, minus the `Reflection.Session`. It seems to be happening when interacting with the host terminal, if that makes any difference. I don't have access to the terminal or database when not at work, so I can't run through it currently. Unless there is another way to simulate it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe does not address your problem but here:

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Set MySession = New Reflection.Session

With ws
    lastrow = getlastrow
```

... there is no connection between `ws` and `lastrow`, unless `ws` happens to be the activesheet (and relying on that will make your code prone to problems)

This would be better:

```
lastrow = getlastrow(ws)
```

and

```
Public Function get_LastRow(ws As Worksheet) As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
With ws
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Cells) <> 0 Then
        LastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", _
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure it's the same thing, but I updated my post with my method of getting the last row in answer to a previous comment. Does this method meet this criteria?

Comment: I posted this after seeing your method, as a suggestion for an improvement to make your code more robust.